# How to know which side of a line will a halfspace $a^Tx \geq c$ fill?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

So given a half-space $a^Tx \geq c$, or $a^Tx \leq c$, how can you tell which "side" of the line $a^Tx = c$ will the space fill? By side I mean that region of space $\mathbb{R}^n$ that belongs to the half-space.And moreover why that "side" in particular. Sure in cases like $n = 2, 3$ one can perform computations, but having an idea how to visualize the half-space should help in convex optimization and linear algebra.

Comment: $a$ points in the "filled" direction of $\{a^T x \ge c\}$.

Comment: The reason is that the dot product $a^T x$ is large when $x$ and $a$ point in similar directions.

Comment: @Milten This might be a trivial question, but can the dot product $a^Tx$ be negative if $a$ and $x$ point in the same direction? That is could it be that $a^Tx < 0$, but $c > 0$?

Comment: No, $a^T x$ is positive when $a$ and $x$ point in the same direction and negative when they point in opposite directions. You can see this from $a^T x = \Vert a \Vert \Vert x \Vert \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them. So the precise statement is that $a^T x\ge 0$ iff $\theta\le \pi/2$ and $a^T x\le 0$ iff $\theta\ge \pi/2$.